# Como remover dados duplicados nessa query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Eai pessoal blz?

Seguinte estou utilizando essa query:

```
select 
    products.id as product_id, 
    offers.id as offer_id, 
    companies.id as company_id, 
    products.title, 
    (ST_Distance(companies.location, 'POINT(-48.030322 -15.839689)':: geography) / 1000)  as distance

from offers 

inner join products on offers.product_id = products.id 
inner join categories on products.category_id = categories.id 
inner join offer_company on offers.id = offer_company.offer_id 
inner join companies on offer_company.company_id = companies.id 

where 
    offers.start_at <= '2016-09-02 13:07:31' and
    offers.deadline >= '2016-09-02 13:07:31' and
    products.category_id in (2) and
    ST_DWithin(companies.location, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-48.030322,-15.839689), 4326), 30000) 
order by 1,2,5
```

e o resultado esta vindo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faço pra poder limitar apenas pra company_id mais próxima? Dessa maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso de alguma maneira exibir a oferta mais próxima, porém ela pode estar em um ou mais lojas (company_id).

Comment: Você quer a primeira linha dos dados duplicados?

Comment: é. mas é isso mesmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando a cláusula [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) junto de [`OVER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
select 
    products.id as product_id, 
    offers.id as offer_id, 
    companies.id as company_id, 
    products.title, 
    (ST_Distance(companies.location, 'POINT(-48.030322 -15.839689)':: geography) / 1000)  as distance,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY products.id,offers.id,companies.id) as n_row
from offers 

inner join products on offers.product_id = products.id 
inner join categories on products.category_id = categories.id 
inner join offer_company on offers.id = offer_company.offer_id 
inner join companies on offer_company.company_id = companies.id 

where 
    offers.start_at <= '2016-09-02 13:07:31' and
    offers.deadline >= '2016-09-02 13:07:31' and
    products.category_id in (2) and
    ST_DWithin(companies.location, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-48.030322,-15.839689), 4326), 30000) 
order by 1,2,5
) t WHERE n_row = 1
```

`ROW_NUMBER` contará o número de linhas retornadas, utilizando em conjunto com a cláusula `OVER` com o parâmetro `PARTITION BY` ele contará as linhas a partir dos campos informados.

Comment: Entendi a lógica e não conhecia esse recurso, estou lendo a respeito aqui, mas em todas as linhas o n_row esta retornando 1 ainda.

Comment: Como assim? Você viu que sua query se tornou uma subquery e pego apenas os resultados dela em que a linha seja igual a 1? Está retornando repetido?

Comment: Sim.. porem se eu rodo a subquery, ela esta retornando exatamente como antes.

Comment: Pode colar  o resultado num pastebin ou algo?

Comment: Então, acho que eu confundi vocês.. as imagens que estão no post inicial já são dos resultados. não é a estrutura das tabelas. entendeu?

Comment: Entendi, mas falei do resultado retornado com a minha resposta.

Comment: Sua resposta estava certa porém usei ela da seguinte maneira row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY offers.id) as n_row, ai sim deu certo

Comment: Bem, pelo menos entendeu como funciona haha (:

Answer (score 0):

Use o [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734.aspx), agrupado pelo campo que voce quer usar pra diferenciar e ordenado pelo valor que quer usar para pegar o primeiro (no exemplo que voce colocou seria  o  menor distance) Depois disso, faça um SELECT sobre esse ultimo comando, pegando apenas os com `ROW_NUMBER  = 1`

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY distance) as ID, *resto do select*
) TABELA
 WHERE ID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja se ajuda.

```
 select 
    products.id as product_id, 
    offers.id as offer_id, 
    companies.id as company_id, 
    products.title, 
    ST_Distance(companies.location, 'POINT(-48.030322 -15.839689)':: geography) / 1000)as distance

from offers 
inner join products on offers.product_id = products.id 
inner join categories on products.category_id = categories.id 
inner join offer_company on offers.id = offer_company.offer_id 
inner join companies on offer_company.company_id = companies.id
(select * from companies where offer_company.company_id = companies.id limit 1) as companies 
on offer_company.company_id = companies.id 
where 
    offers.start_at <= '2016-09-02 13:07:31' and
    offers.deadline >= '2016-09-02 13:07:31' and
    products.category_id in (2) and
    ST_DWithin(companies.location, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-48.030322,-15.839689), 4326), 30000) 
order by 1,2,5
```

Comment: vc removeu o join do company?? acho q foi isso.. mas eu preciso dele..

Comment: Verdade não vi isso.